# Great amount of diskspace is used and I hardly have any files

Tags: disk-usage

I've recently installed Lubuntu and copied a great amount of things to it and deleted them. The issue is that the diskspace is still taken. I've emptied the trash too. For some reason the root folder (/) and within that the "home" folder.....seems to contain all those deleted files, although I cannot locate them. Can anyone tell me why this is and how I could solve it?

NOTE: I've just found the folder where all the "extra" space is......home/username/.local/share/Trash/expunged.....
I deleted the contents of the folder, restarted the laptop and the space is still not liberated.

Comment: You can use "Disk Usage Analyzer" to check which folder is taking more space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not clear myself why this happened but i can help you locate them

Open you Home Folder and do [ctrl - h] to reveal hidden folders

Navigate to /.local/share/Trash/expunged to remove the files permanently

Do not remove these folder however

Comment: @Stephen_Myall That's what I did....I removed the contents of the expunged, but no luck at all.